Is file still opening after using np.loadtxt(file)?
I have a plaix txt file named, for example, a.txt. Then I need many program to read it, so I use multiprocessing module to achieve it. In every program, I use numpy.loadtxt to read a.txt. Then I found that, when I open too much program, such as 600, all program block. And I found there is a lock in program. After searching some information about this topic, I guess that after numpy.loadtxt , the file object is still opening, so other program need to wait the file closing. Is file still opening after using np.loadtxt(file) ? And how can I know whether a file is closing or not.
After searching some information about this topic, I guess that after numpy.loadtxt , the file object is still opening, so other program need to wait the file closing. Is file still opening after using np.loadtxt(file) ? And how can I know whether a file is closing or not.

file.closed tells you if file is closed. File objects are derived from io.IOBase.

@MichaelButscher How can I use file.closed after np.loadtxt ?

numpy.loadtxt() does not leave an open (dangling) file descriptor.
Proof:
import numpy as np
import psutil

print(psutil.Process().open_files())
np.loadtxt("foo.txt")
print(psutil.Process().open_files())

Output:
[]
[]


loadtxt also accepts a file object instead of a path and the documentation doesn't tell what happens to this file object after data was read. You can try it out but there is no written guarantee that all numpy versions behave in the same way.

@MichaelButscher If you pass a file "handle" then the underlying code is extremely unlikely to close it. That would be up to the caller. There's no detail in the OP about how np.loadtext() is being called.

But what happened when many program load this txt in the same time? Because when I use with open() as f: to read the txt, the program in multiprocessing no longer blocked.

@MengMai If you do not have the problem when using a context manager it implies that the fault is in your original code (which you've chosen not to share). Basically, you're not closing the file(s)
